# Lord of the Ring LCG: Silvan Refugee forced effect

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg

When I use "The Tree People" to return a Silvan ally in my hand, does the forced effect on "Silvan Refugee" trigger?
More generally, does returning an ally to one's hand count as this character leaving play/being dead?

**The Tree People** (Event)

> **Action**: Return a ***Silvan*** ally you control to your hand to search the top 5 cards of your deck for a Silvan ally. Put that ally into play and shuffle the other cards back into your deck. You can only play 1 copy of The Tree People each phase.

**Silvan Refugee** (Ally)

> **Forced**: After a character leaves play, discard Silvan Refugee from play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, no matter where it goes from play, to discard, to deck or to hand as your case asks for, the card is no longer in play, so the forced of Refugee will trigger.

If however you use The Tree People to return Silvan Refugee to your hand, it will no longer be in play to trigger, letting you replay the relatively cheap Refugee again later.

Comment: While correct, this answer could be improved by a reference to the rules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I might have to rethink my strategy a bit then. I wasn't resolving the forced effect until now.